# How to pass a nested dictionary as a header in python-requests?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

My header is of the following format

```
import requests

header = {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "a": {"b": "b_value"},
          "some_param": {"some_key_value": "some_string"},
         }

res = requests.post(url, json=z_data, headers=header)
```

I am getting the error that value of dictionary cannot be a dictionary.
I tried using `json.dumps()` but it ignored the contents inside of it.

Please help me in resolving this error. Thank you,

Comment: What should be the request parameters? They have to be strings...

Comment: The solution really just depends on what post parameters the form expects. So, what parameters does the form expect?

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes they are strings, I have updated the question

Comment: @user10987432 they are user defined parameters

Comment: A header is (string, string) pair. Your header `a` has a dictionary as a value. That won't work. You have to convert it to a string.

Comment: @freakish I tried converting the dictionary to string, it was just ignored by the server

Comment: Could you please answer the question: what should be **exactly** the request parameter for a and b? I know that the have to be strings, but in the header dictionaries, you have `dict` objects

Comment: @SergeBallesta the header is a nested dictionary where the value for parameter ```a``` is a dictionary and the value of the parameter ```b```  is a string(```b-value```). Hope I made myself clear now.

Comment: You cannot pass a dictionnary in a HTTP request. Full stop. The HTTP protocol requires any parameter to be a string. So the question boils down to *how to you want to format the dictionary*?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I just want to the dictionary to be passed to the server. I used ```json.dumps``` as well as I converted the (inside)dictionary explicitly to a string. Both the options made the header values to be ignored by the server.

Comment: Also I came across this [issue](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5058)

Answer (score 2):

You must json encode the parameters:

```
header = {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "a": json.dumps({"b": "b_value"}),
          "some_param": json.dumps({"some_key_value": "some_string"})
         }
```

If you receive a pre-built `header` dictionary, you will have to pre-process it:

```
header = {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "a": {"b": "b_value"},
          "some_param": {"some_key_value": "some_string"},
         }

...

header = {k: json.dumps(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v for k,v in header.items()}
res = requests.post(url, json=z_data, headers=header)
```

Comment: I used json.dumps() earlier as well but to no avail., the dictionary data is being ignored when encasing it in ```json.dumps()``` . Seems like this is some other issue beyond my scope. Thanks for the help, though

Comment: @JohnDoe: That should be the way to go... If you experience problem when using it, please ask a new question with a [mcve] and say what is the server or what it expects.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the parameters should be json-like strings.
Using the json module should work, but you can try f-strings instead:

```
header = {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "a": f'{{"b": {b_value} }}',
          "c": f'{{"d": {d_value} }}',
         }
```

That way your variables a and c are strings and the variables `b_value` and `d_value` will be replaced with its contents.

Comment: The ```b_value``` and ```d_value``` are strings, not variables

Comment: In that case just put a string there: `... "a": '{"b": "stringcontent" }'`